# Running VS2022 as Different User Trial License Expired Freezes IDE

Tags: visual-studio, ide, licensing

I have a Visual Studio license that I normally run during development - everything is working fine when I launch VS directly. However, when testing in our different environments I need to run VS under a different user. I use "Run as Different User" to accomplish that:

[image]

Once I launched it runs great... Until today when my trial license expired. This is obvious because the different user doesn't have a VS License.

[image]

My thoughts are to update the license but when I do get this message:
[image]

Visual Studio completely freezes and the only way to continue is to kill process using Task Manager.

Has anyone encountered this problem? More importantly, does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to uninstall & reinstall VS 2022. Once I launched it I was able to enter my VS Subscription credentials to get passed the trial period from the start.

When I launched VS 2022 under a different it prompted me for my subscription credentials. I entered the same credentials as before.

Works like charm!

I suspect I ran into this problem because I used the trial period while waiting for my VS Subscription to be established. Something screwy in the previous installation must have gone wrong and wouldn't allow me to enter my subscription credentials when I ran it as a different user.

Hope this helps someone experiencing the same issue.